# Vaadin: What is the Spring context of the Drop component?

Tags: spring-security, vaadin, drop, security-context

I am using the 21 version of Vaadin. I have the following code, taken from an example from the Vaadin website
and slightly (purely beauty) modified by me. The remaining files are unchanged.

the codes are given below. Why do I get such a log?

2022-01-20 10:08:32.589 DEBUG 12556 --- [nio-8888-exec-6] c.e.photoarchive.components.DropView     : Place 1. User here 
2022-01-20 10:08:38.197 TRACE 12556 --- [nio-8888-exec-1] c.example.photoarchive.SecurityService   : **authentication is null**
2022-01-20 10:08:38.197 DEBUG 12556 --- [nio-8888-exec-1] c.e.photoarchive.components.DropView     : Place 2. User here <>

```
@Log4j2
@Route(value = "drop", layout = MainAppLayout.class)
public class DropView extends VerticalLayout implements HasComponents {
    private final SecurityService securityService;

    public DropView(SecurityService securityService) {
        this.securityService = securityService;

        MultiFileMemoryBuffer buffer = new MultiFileMemoryBuffer();
        Upload upload = new Upload(buffer);
        upload.setUploadButton(new Button(getTranslation("Upload_files")));
        upload.setDropLabel(new Label(getTranslation("Drop_files")));
        upload.setMaxFileSize(-1);

        log.debug("Place 1. User here <{}>", getUsername());

        upload.addFinishedListener(e -> {
            log.debug("Place 2. User here <{}>", getUsername());
            // my code ... too much :-)
        });
        add(upload);
    }

    private String getUsername() {
        var user = securityService.getAuthenticatedUser();
        if (user != null) return user.getUsername();
        return "";
    }
}


@Log4j2
@Service
public class SecurityService {
    private static final String LOGOUT_SUCCESS_URL = "/";

    public UserDetails getAuthenticatedUser() {
        SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
        if (Objects.isNull(context)) {log.trace("context is null");return null;}

        Authentication authentication = context.getAuthentication();
        if (Objects.isNull(authentication)) {log.trace("authentication is null");return null;}

        Object principal = authentication.getPrincipal();
        if (Objects.isNull(principal)) {log.trace("principal is null");return null;}

        if (principal instanceof UserDetails) {
            return (UserDetails) principal;
        }
        // Anonymous or no authentication.
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you logged in? How do you use Spring Security?

Comment: of couse! 
Log:
2022-01-20 10:08:32.589 DEBUG 12556 --- c.e.photoarchive.components.DropView : Place 1. User here <user>
2022-01-20 10:08:38.197 TRACE 12556 --- c.example.photoarchive.SecurityService : authentication is null 
2022-01-20 10:08:38.197 DEBUG 12556 --- c.e.photoarchive.components.DropView : Place 2. User here <>